# Select auto filled text in input react

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, input

I have an input in my React website. It has autofill functionality. I want to selected **autofilled** part of the text in input like it happens when you type something in google. When running my code (provided below), when I type 'do' it autofills 'dog walking' as it should, but selects nothing, then if I press backspace it removes the last letter and then selects the autofilled part of the text. My question is: why text is not selected before pressing a backspace?

---

input:

```
<input
        type={'text'}
        placeholder={'Search'}
        name={'search'}
        onChange={this.onChange}
        value={this.state.searchTitle}
        style={{
          paddingLeft: 16,
          width: '100%',
          fontFamily: 'tbc',
          marginBottom: 5,
          borderWidth: 0,
        }}
        id={'search-input'}
/>
```

---

Initial state:

```
state = {
    searchTitle: '',
    suggestions: fakeServices,
    showSuggestions: false,
    selection: {
      selectionStart: 0,
      selectionEnd: 0
    },
};
```

---

Function called when text is changed:

```
onChange = (event) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    const prevTextLength = this.state.searchTitle.length;

    this.setState({
      searchTitle: text,
      selection: {
        selectionStart: 0,
        selectionEnd: 0
      }
    });

    // Searching for suggestions and placing them into the state 
    if (text !== '') {
      const filteredServices = fuse.search(text);
      this.setState({
        showSuggestions: true,
        suggestions: filteredServices,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showSuggestions: false,
      })
    }

    if (this.state.suggestions.length !== 0 && text.length > prevTextLength) {
      this.setState({
        searchTitle: this.state.suggestions[0].title,
        selection: {
          selectionStart: text.length,
          selectionEnd: this.state.suggestions[0].title.length
        }
      });
    }

    const input = document.getElementById('search-input');

    input.focus();
    input.selectionStart = this.state.selection.selectionStart;
    input.selectionEnd = this.state.selection.selectionEnd;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that text would be selected, but after that component updates and the selection disappears. Solution is to place the code responsible for selection in componentDidUpdate() lifecycle function:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const input = document.getElementById('search-input');
    input.focus();
    input.selectionStart = this.state.selection.selectionStart;
    input.selectionEnd = this.state.selection.selectionEnd;
}
```